# how can I uppload images with carrierwave ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here is my create

```
$('.new_book').bind 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->    
    res = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)    
    result = createBooks(res)                           
    $('.drafts').append(result)
```

here is form_for

```
   =form_for @user.books.new, multipart: true, remote: true, authenticity_token: true, remote: true do |f|
      p
        =f.label :title
      p
        =f.text_field :title
      p
        =f.label :author
      p
        =f.text_field :author
      p
        =f.label :description
      p
        =f.text_area :description
      p
        =f.file_field :front
      p
        =f.submit
```

and controller

```
def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  @book.user = current_user
  @book.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json{ render json: { book: @book } }
  end    
end
```

Im using simple carrierwave and recieving unknown format. can anybody help?

Comment: What kind of help you want? Write code for you?

Comment: may be some links or advise. Cause I dont know even a direction to move to

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: did you install the gems necessary 
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.11.2'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.5.1'
gem 'fog',                     '1.38.0'

permitted the params required for the picture?

Comment: Ok my advice
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts

read the last bit of this it's talking about using carrier wave and it certainly will help.

Comment: no I only installed a 'carrierwave' Im trying to lean by viewing RailsCasts and nothing was sad there about them. What is the full list of gems I need? I want to explore them

Answer (score 0):

The best and anser on my question is here http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/handling-file-upload-using-ruby-on-rails-5-api